# Make a variable based on a pattern for sas dataset

Tags: dataset, sas

I made a dataset with random numbers for outcome and an observation. I want every other value to be 0 and the other to be 1 but I'm unsure how to proceed. Is there a way I can tell sas to either do a pattern  or give all evens a value or something?

```
 id      outcome     trt
 1         1          0
 2         1          1
 3         0          0
  4        1          1
```

etc. I looked at maybe using mod but from what I understand it will take values out of my dataset not create the information treatment.

Answer (score 1):

MOD is a function. Functions have arguments, and return a value. MOD will work for you. *N* is an automatic variable that counts how many times a data step has iterated.   Try:

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  trt = mod(_n_,2) ;
run ;
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense! I see where I got confused.

Comment: If Quentin's answer was helpful for you, please consider clicking the accept button next to the question to indicate that your problem is resolved.  This also provides a reputation bonus for Quentin and for you, which encourages users to participate on the site.